# iOS SwiftUI - update variable based on view height on appear

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have this variable:

```
@State var profileViewHeight: CGFloat = 200
```

and I need to update it based on a view as soon as it appears

This is what I've tried:

```
    GeometryReader { geo in
        userProfileView(uid: uid, userid: self.$userid, offsetMenu: self.$offsetMenu, closeThisView: closeThisView)
            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
            .background(Color.teal)
            .padding(.bottom, profileViewOffset)
            .offset(y: profileViewOffset)
            .zIndex(2)
        
        profileViewHeight = geo.size.height
    }
```

and I get the

```
Type '()' cannot conform to 'View'
```

error.

I also tried:

```
    .onAppear(){
        profileViewHeight = geo.size.height
    }
```

but the ui gets bugged this way.

Please help

Comment: I know that I can't just use code there, I just posted it as pseudo code to show what I want

Comment: As you are passing the value not a binding, is there any reason why you do not use geo.size directly ?

Comment: @PtitXav how? I'm new to ios/swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it :D

```
.background(
    GeometryReader { geo in

        Color.clear
            .onAppear {
                profileViewHeight = geo.size.height
            }
    }
)
```

but it looks like it still creates an ui bug, I'll accept a solution which is better than this one

Answer (score 0):

What I meant :

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    userProfileView(uid: uid, userid: self.$userid, offsetMenu: self.$offsetMenu, closeThisView: closeThisView)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .background(Color.teal)
        .padding(.bottom, geo.size.height)
        .offset(y: geo.size.height)
        .zIndex(2)
}
```

or

```
GeometryReader { geo in
    let profileViewHeight = geo.size.height
    userProfileView(uid: uid, userid: self.$userid, offsetMenu: self.$offsetMenu, closeThisView: closeThisView)
        .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
        .background(Color.teal)
        .padding(.bottom, profileViewOffset)
        .offset(y: profileViewHeight)
        .zIndex(2)
}
```

Try simple first

Comment: No because the offset is based on more factors and not just the height of one view and is constantly updated while scrolling

Comment: Can you provide more contents ?